# Отображение не растягивающейся текстуры

Tags: javascript, three.js

Отображаю с помощью three.js 3д объект из 3DSMax. Ставлю текстуру на 3д объект. Эта текстура растягивается на всю поверхность 3д объекта. Как сделать так, чтобы текстура не растягивалась, а была определённого размера, который я сам укажу? Т.е. если файл текстуры img.jpg имеет размер 250х250 пикселей, то и на объекте эта текстура будет занимать только 250х250 пикселей, а не растягивалась на всю поверхность объекта.

Вот код:

```
loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('3d/women.obj', function (geometry) {
    if (mesh) scene.remove(mesh);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("3d/texture.png");
    material.map = texture;

    geometry.children[0].material = material;
    mesh = geometry;

    geometry.scale.set(15, 15, 15);
    geometry.position.y = -150;

    scene.add(geometry);
});
```

Но он растягивает картинку texture.png на всю поверхность 3д объекта women.obj, а мне нужно чтобы не растягивался.

Comment: не ясно что имеется ввиду под "не растягивающейся текстурой". С помощью тестурных координат можно получить любой участок текстуры (изображения)

Comment: Грубо говоря, у меня есть Teapot из 3dsmax, мне нужно поставить фото на боковую поверхность этого чайника, но методом, который я указал выше, фото растягивается на всю поверхность чайника. Как бы сделать, чтобы только на боковую сторону чайника и только с размером фотографии?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете указать смещение и масштаб текстуры:

```
texture.repeat.set(2, 2); // отобразить текстуру уменьшенную в 2 раза
texture.offset.set(0.25, 0.25); // сдвинуть текстуру на 25%
```

Вот полная справка (http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Textures/Texture)

Answer (score 1):

Отображение текстуры зависит от текстурных координат, которые вы настроите. Вы можете использовать файлы текстур любого размера, однако, по моему опыту с threejs r71 текстура будет автоматически масштабирована, если ее размеры не соответствуют `2 в степени n`, т.е. текстура 600х600 будет масштабирована к 512х512 и в консоли будет выдано предупреждение.

Чтобы создать текстурные координаты в 3DS Max вы можете использовать, например, модификатор "Unwrap UVW".

Пример того, как это выглядит в 3DMax (*Максом не занимаюсь, поэтому прошу строго за пример не судить.*):
[image: Unwrap UVW пример]

В правом верхнем углу я разместил то, что мне не требуется.

Пример текстуры (в данном случае для bump, но суть та же):
[image: Bump map пример]

После этого вы экспортируете свою 3D модель, например, в формате *.obj

[image: Окно экспорта 3ds max в формат obj]

С галочкой "Texture coordinates". Также, вы можете настроить "Export materials" (будет экспортирована текстура и *.mtl файл с настройками цвета и еще нескольких параметров)

В данном случае я использую текстуру размером 512х512, однако, можно выбрать и другой размер (1024х1024, 2048х2048, 256х256). Текстура все равно будет использоваться соответственно текстурным координатам, а ее размер будет влиять на качество результата (мне 256 не подошло, т.к. было низкое качество, а 1024х1024 имела большой вес в килобайтах).

Финальный результат на сайте (пупырашками покрыта только верхняя часть):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду пробовать!